# How can my Cocoa application be notified of onClick events in a WebView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, webview

I'm loading a `WebView` in my OSX application and want to receive a notification in my app when the user clicks on an element in the `WebView`. (The `WebView` is loading a web page that is part of my web application.)

Is this possible?

I can think of a way to do it (poll a javascript value that gets set on the `click` event) but I'm hoping there's a more sensible way!

Answer (score 5):

Since the web page is your web application, then I assume you have control over the html.

Use [WebScript](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/appleapplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/Tasks/ObjCFromJavaScript.html).

Here's a little demo:

Objective-C:

```
- (void)windowDidLoad{
    [[webView windowScriptObject] setValue:self forKey:@"objcConnector"];
    ....
}
+ (BOOL)isSelectorExcludedFromWebScript:(SEL)aSelector{
    if (aSelector == @selector(elementClicked:)) return NO;
    return YES;
}
-(void)elementClicked:(id)object{
    //object is the id of the element
}
```

HTML:

```
<button id="example" onClick="window.objcConnector.elementClicked_(this.id)">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this delegate method should be useful.
Open a link from the WebView would call this method, so you can figure out what to do with it.

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender
        decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(NSDictionary *)actionInformation
        request:(NSURLRequest *)request frame:(WebFrame *)frame
        decisionListener:(id<WebPolicyDecisionListener>)listener
```

Or you can listen to the WebView frame change URL :

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender didFinishLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame
```

Comment: Seems promising, I'll have a look at it. Do you know if this would work for anchor click events that aren't for navigating to another page (ie are handled using javascript)? I wonder if it's only trigger by a change to `window.location`.

Comment: Damn, this delegate method is only called for navigation events - not for clicks on anchors that are handled with javascript.

Comment: Yeah, if you wanna do that, you should consider checking JavascriptCore. You can probably create your own javascript function in Obj-C, and then call it from your WebView.

Answer (score 1):

Subclass NSWindow and catch the mouse down events on the WebView which is actually a WebHTMLView:

```
@interface MyWindow : NSWindow
@end

@implementation MyWindow

- (void)sendEvent:(NSEvent *)event
{

    if ([event type] == NSLeftMouseDown || [event type] == NSRightMouseDown)
    {
        NSView *deepView = [[self contentView] hitTest:[event locationInWindow]];
        if([[deepView className] isEqualToString:@"WebHTMLView"]){
            return;
        }
    }
    [super sendEvent:event];

}

@end
```

Then by monitoring the mouse over element delegate method you can track which element was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Malhal's solution did not work for me in Mac OS.  WebView in Mac OS is weird and wkWebView is incomplete.

Having set the first responder to the webView, this one did:

```
- (void)sendEvent:(NSEvent *)event
{

if ([event type] == NSLeftMouseDown || [event type] == NSRightMouseDown)
{

    if([[self.firstResponder className] isEqualToString:@"WebHTMLView"])
    {
        NSLog(@"MouseDown at: %f, %f",event.locationInWindow.x,event.locationInWindow.y);
        return;
    }
}
[super sendEvent:event];

}
```